# Запятые лучше казнить или можно помиловать? )

Tags: пунктуация

Мы [ищем и исправляем](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4129) ошибки в [справке Stack Overflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Есть два момента с запятыми, в которых я не уверена. Буду благодарна за компетентную помощь.

```
... , которые ... не относятся к тематике Stack Overflow на русском, согласно определению в Справке.
```

перед "согласно" оставить запятую или удалить?

```
Ваше простое искреннее «спасибо» очень ценно, но это не все, чем вы можете отблагодарить ответившего — проголосуйте за ответы,
```

Нужна запятая перед тире?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Обстоятельства обособляются **факультативно** (то есть обособление остается на усмотрение автора):

Если обстоятельство выражено существительным с предлогом или без предлога; ***чаще всего обособляются обстоятельства, выраженные существительными с предлогами благодаря, в зависимости от, вопреки, в связи с, вследствие, несмотря на, согласно, в соответствии с, ввиду, во избежание*** и др. [Обособленное обстоятельство](http://bitclass.ru/rus/theory/%D0%A1%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE)

**Поэтому в первом примере перед "согласно" Вы можете поставить запятую.**

Во втором примере можно поставить двоеточие на месте А ИМЕННО:

***...это не все, чем вы можете отблагодарить ответившего: (а именно) проголосуйте за ответы...***

**Если же Вы ставите **тире, то запятая перед ним нужна**: **она закрывает придаточное предложение.**

***...это не все, чем вы можете отблагодарить ответившего, — проголосуйте за ответы...***